# Blocked iCloud email account

Tags: icloud, email

Until 2 December by home security camera sent email alerts to my iCloud mail accounts from another home email account which I also use on my Mac. Since then emails have been returned undelivered, apparently blocked by Apple.  Test messages from my Mac to my iCloud account are similarly returned, though traffic is still being received in the iCloud account from other sources.  The CCTV alerts are not being sent to the junk folder.  How can I find out what is going on?

Below is the returned mail message I typically receive, Proofpoint tells me that the sovision SMTP mail server address, 109.228.41.85, is not blacklisted.

```
*********
This is the Postfix program at host sv0.sovision.net.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to <postmaster>

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

            The Postfix program

<colinmccleery@me.com>: host mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.68] said: 550 5.7.0
   Blocked - see
   https://support.proofpoint.com/dnsbl-lookup.cgi?ip=109.228.41.85:
   colinmccleery@me.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; sv0.sovision.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: B95E877C147
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; colin@mccleery.org
Arrival-Date: Thu,  3 Dec 2015 11:10:00 +0000 (GMT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; colinmccleery@me.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; host mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.68] said: 550
   5.7.0 Blocked - see
   https://support.proofpoint.com/dnsbl-lookup.cgi?ip=109.228.41.85:
   colinmccleery@me.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)

From: <colin@mccleery.org>
Date: 3 December 2015 at 11:11:51 GMT
To: <colinmccleery@me.com>
Subject: 00626E4841B8(Front) motion alarm at 20151203121146

************
```

Comment: "Proofpoint tells me ... not blacklisted" - It's quite possible that the block has since been cleared (if you are only just running this test)? - the email quoted above is from 6 days ago. Incidentally, MX Toolbox (that I mentioned in my answer) still reports that IP address listed on two blacklists: "MAILSPIKE BL" and "SORBS SPAM" - although this might not be significant.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that the mailserver (IP address) through which you send your "home email" has found it's way onto a "blacklist". If iCloud is using this blacklist to filter out potential spam then your email will be blocked.

Sometimes the bounced email will give a clue as to the reason for rejection and which blacklist was used (if any).

You can check if your mailserver's IP address is listed on many of the main blacklists with various tools:

- ["Blacklist Check" on MX Toolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a127.0.0.1)
- [Trend Micro - Email Reputation Services](https://ers.trendmicro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is called „silent email filtering“. Some strings in your email head/body or domain are blacklisted by Apple. This is not legal to block outgoing emails!
Find out which strings are in common in all your emails and mail it to Apple‘s icloudteam (Get in touch with the iCloud Admin Team via icloudadmin@apple.com.). FORGET Apple support, they will not and cannot help you. For details read:
https://miapple.me/apple-icloud-mail-blocks-outbound-emails-silent-filtering-fix/